# LiveCycle drop-down list change event only works on second change

Tags: drop-down-menu, livecycle

I want a Text Field to appear when a certain item is chosen from a drop-down list. I'm using a change event.

```
if(this.rawValue == 1){
Tolerance.presence = "visible";
}
else{
Tolerance.presence = "hidden";
}
```

The problem is that the Text Field  presence does not change immediately when a selection is made, but only after I go back to the list box and select again (any value, not just the same one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new value of the dropdown only registers after the change event. This means `this.rawValue` points to the old value of the dropdown in a change event.

Either move your script dropdown exit event or make use of the `event.newText` in the if conditional in the change event.

Comment: Much appreciated. I come from a vba world and am still learning JavaScript behavior.